# Update wingridview with BindingList

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, bindingsource, bindinglist

I have problems with updating WinGridView after i am pressing my Update Button. I am using BindingList with use of INotifyPropertyChanged property. And still can't get to make my gridview to update.

Below is code from my short test program:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create BindingList
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLconnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectCustomer, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        customerList.Add(new Customers(reader["CntId"].ToString(), reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Surname"].ToString()));
                    }         
                }
            }
        }

        customersBindingSource = new BindingSource(customerList, null);
        ugv_contacts.DataSource = customersBindingSource;

    }

    //update button
    private void btn_UpdateCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(SQLconnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                SqlCommand updateCommand = conDataBase.CreateCommand();
                updateCommand.CommandText = UpdateCustomerDet;

                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CntId", Customer_Id);
                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CntSurname", txt_surname.Text);
                updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CntName", txt_name.Text);

                SqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = updateCommand.ExecuteReader();

                customersBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) //v primeru napake se izvede to
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Customers : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Customers(string id, string surname, string name)
        {
            CntId = id;
            Name = name;
            Surname = surname;
        }

        private string id;
        private string surname;
        private string name;

        public string CntId { get { return id; } set { id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("CntId"); } }
        public string Surname { get { return surname; } set { surname = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Surname"); } }
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); } }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));

        }        
    }
```

Could someone please go throught it and told me what am i doing it wrong? I've searched and tested a lot of stackoverflow questions and still couldn't make my code to work correctly.

---

After some years i am still not quite at the end with the solution.

Could someone please tell me what am i doing wrong? Main problem is that .ResetBindings is not working. And i have no idea why.

Thank you in advance. Below it's my code:

```
 public BindingSource contactSource = new BindingSource();
 public BindingList<Contact> contactList = new BindingList<Contact>();

 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        contactList = GetBindingList_Contacts();
        contactSource = new BindingSource(contactList, null);
        ultraGrid1.DataSource = contactSource;

    }

public BindingList<Contact> GetBindingList_Contacts()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLconnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SelectCustomer, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        contactList.Add(new Contact
                            (
                            Convert.ToInt32(reader["CntId"]), reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Surname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(reader["CntAge"])
                            )
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new BindingList<Contact>(contactList);
    }

private void btn_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(ultraGrid1.ActiveRow.ListIndex);

        contactList[row].FirstName = txt_name.Text;
        contactList[row].LastName = txt_surname.Text;
        contactList[row].Age = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Age.Text);
        //function that updated DB

    }

private void btn_refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contactSource.ResetBindings(true);
    }

public static Contact GetBL_Contacts(int CntId)
    {
        Contact CtnDetail = new Contact();
        using (SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(SQLconnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                SqlCommand selectCommand = conDataBase.CreateCommand();
                selectCommand.CommandText = GetCustomerDetail;
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CntId", CntId);

                SqlDataReader myReader;
                myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    //produkt data
                    int sCntId = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["CntId"].ToString());
                    string sCntSurname = myReader["Surname"].ToString();
                    string sCntName = myReader["Name"].ToString();
                    int sCntAge = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["CntAge"]);

                    CtnDetail = new Contact
                    {
                        Id = sCntId,
                        FirstName = sCntName,
                        LastName = sCntSurname,
                        Age = sCntAge
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //v primeru napake se izvede to
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return CtnDetail;
    }
}
```

Class Contact

```
   public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private int id;
private string firstName;
private string lastName;
private int age;

public Contact(int id, string firstName, string lastName, int age)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}

public Contact()
{

}

protected virtual void OnPropretyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public int Id { get { return this.id; } set { if (this.id != value) { this.id = value; this.OnPropretyChanged("Id"); } } }
public string FirstName { get { return this.firstName; } set { if (this.firstName != value) { this.firstName = value; this.OnPropretyChanged("FirstName"); } } }
public string LastName { get { return this.lastName; } set { if (this.lastName != value) { this.lastName = value; this.OnPropretyChanged("LastName"); } } }
public int Age { get { return this.age; } set { if (this.age != value) { this.age = value; this.OnPropretyChanged("Age"); } } }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: You didn't post any code where you changed a Customer's property.

Comment: That's because i don't have any. :) I have troubles understanding this concept, since this is all new to me. How should i proceed further? Thank you

Comment: I change it with button Update. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Could someone please help me? This is the only thing which i am missing.

Comment: Not clear what issue you are still trying to solve.  What did you expect to happen when you called `contactSource.ResetBindings(true);`?

Comment: I have application for creating quotations. Each quotation has it's status. I have grid with all actual quotations (all quotation with status opened, pending and confirmed are shown). If i change status to Cancelled this quotation should be erased from that grid. For now only way to achieve this is to close application and re-open it - not at all user friendly. I was expecting same behaviour as i was using standard population of grid with datasource without databinding. If i call ultraGrid1.DataSource = contactSource; once again i have dubled records in my grid.

Comment: I don't see any code that removes an item from `customerList` or `contactList`.

Comment: in this test application i didn't use it yet.  
    UltraGridRow row = ultraGrid1.ActiveRow;
    Contact cust = contactList[row.Index];
    if (cust != null)
    { contactList.Remove(cust); }

Comment: and that i would delete record also from DB (SQL query). Also when i have multiple users and with this solution which i am currently using it, every user see only their changes in grid, not changes from other users. Unless user closes the application and re-open it. Because then contactSource is fresh from DB with all changes. I must be honest, i don't understand this concept of ibindinglist and INotifyPropertyChanged function.

Comment: Yeah, binding doesn't work like that.  Binding is a way to keep your controls in sync with your collection.  It does NOT automatically poll the database for any changes there.  So yes, you need to call the database again to keep your collection in sync with what other users are doing on their machines.  You could look into [SQL Server Event Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-notification-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for explanations. So if i want all grid data to be read from DB, i must first clear bindinglist and then repopulate it with SQL? So i call myBindingList.Clear(); and then repopulate grid? This is the only solution?  Problem is that then i loose focus on chosen record in grid. And focus (active row) must be stored and then read manually in code?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.  I did give a link in the previous comment regarding events when the database has changes.